# how to hide page URLs from the website visitor?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, rewriting

Whenever a user clicks a link like `www.mywebsite.com/hello.php`, I want `www.mywebsite.com` to appear in his address bar. I tried modifying the .htaccess file for this. The rules worked for the home page. But whenever I click a link, the php page for that link appears in the address bar. How can I hide the names of page even after a link is clicked.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^site$ /*.php [L]
```

Eg. When I type `mywebsite.com/index.php` it shows only `mywebsite.com`. But if I click a link in the page, like `<a href="mypage.php">My Page</a>`, `mywebsite.com/mypage.php` appears in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

In *.htaccess*, add a redirection rule for each of your paths.  Each rule will tell the server which webpage to serve when the browser requests a human friendly paths. For instance:

```
Rewrite On
RewriteRule ^home/?$          /home.php      [END,NC]
RewriteRule ^about/?$         /about.php     [END,NC]
RewriteRule ^products/?$      /pages/products.php      [END,NC]
...
```

Then in your pages, use the pretty links for hrefs:

```
<a href="/products">Products</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two problems here:

1. Your link `<a href="mypage.php">My Page</a>` should be `<a href="mypage">My Page</a>`
2. From what I understand you don't only want one specific URL to be forwarded, so you should write a more general rule like `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php`. This lets you access any URL without the `.php`extension.